# Anyone know how to wait bash until the linux kernel has fully booted?

Tags: linux, embedded, kernel

I put a nice welcome message in my embedded Linux. You can see it, because the kernels boot messages push it off the screen. I know bash read my .bashrc file because the aliases and
other data are there. I need something more intelligent than a sleep to wait for the kernel to be really up, and finished with outputting all of its messages.

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

You can put bash script for displaying welcome message in end of init.rC or /etc/init.d/rcS file